# Problemas copm o pacote "dns" em Python

Tags: python

Estou com um problema em um script onde preciso utilizar o pacote dns em Python.

```
import dns.resolver
```

E para executar uma simples verificação de DNS:

```
my_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
my_resolver.nameservers = ['8.8.8.8']
records = my_resolver.query(domain, 'MX')
```

Já instalei o pacote, e continuo com o seguinte erro:

```
    records = my_resolver.query(domain, 'MX')
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/dns/resolver.py", line 1036, in query
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/dns/resolver.py", line 233, in __init__
dns.resolver.NoAnswer: The DNS response does not contain an answer to the question: uol.com.br. IN MX
```

Alguma dica?

Answer (score 0):

```
import dns.resolver

def lista_mx(hosts):
    return ['\n'.join(map(str,[resul for resul in [dns.resolver.query(host, 'MX') for host in hosts][i]])) for i in range(hosts.__len__())]
if __name__ == "__main__":
    hosts = ['google.com','uol.com.br','hawksec.com.br']
    for i in lista_mx(hosts):
        print(i)

40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
10 aspmx.l.google.com.
50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
10 mx.uol.com.br.
10 webserver01.floripa.com.br.
```

http://www.dnspython.org/examples.html